# dbms_output.put_line not printing inside procedure even after 'set serveroutput on'

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

The below procedure executes fine but the 'dbms' inside it does not print any output.( procedure meant to jot out the names of the emps whose salaries are yet to be entered in the table)
The table has two columns i.e 1)name_of_emp 2)salary (default 0)

```
create or replace procedure add_sal_info
as
    cursor c is select * from emp_earnings;
    cname varchar2(30);
    csal number(5);

begin
    open c;

    while(c%found) loop
        fetch c into cname, csal;
        if (csal = 0) then
            dbms_output.put_line('enter salary for : ' ||' '|| cname);
        end if;
    end loop;

    close c;
end;
/
```

The serveroutput is set to 'on' and i get the message "procedure completed successfully" on execute but it does not print the names of emps whose salaries are not entered (there are a few of them in the table).
any crux here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`c%found` is not true until you have fetched a row, therefore you never enter the loop. It's a code structure issue not a `dbms_output` issue.

By the way, this could be simplified to:

```
create or replace procedure add_sal_info
as
    cursor c is select * from emp_earnings;
begin
    for r in c loop
        if r.csal = 0 then
            dbms_output.put_line('enter salary for : ' ||' '|| r.cname);
        end if;
    end loop;
end;
```

or even

```
create or replace procedure add_sal_info
as
begin
    for r in (
        select * from emp_earnings
    )
    loop
        if r.csal = 0 then
            dbms_output.put_line('enter salary for : ' ||' '|| r.cname);
        end if;
    end loop;
end;
```

PL/SQL doesn't have brackets around `if` or `while` conditions (it has the `then` keyword instead). You can put them there but they are ignored.

Comment: Glad it helped. (Just edited to add a simplified version.)